# Wiener process Vs. Continuous Function

Tags: analysis, statistics, optimization

I am reading the following  paper

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1e87/6efc4fa38eb4de9cb0f17dddc3a28c6a8e34.pdf?_ga=2.82974751.843375952.1610365035-1651787130.1583361034

Here (in p. 1), is stated the following:

*In this paper we propose an algorithm for approximating the global minimum of a
continuous function f defined on the unit interval. Under the assumption that f is a
random function distributed according to the Wiener measure, we establish an asymptotic
upper bound on its approximation error.*

Next, it is said: "Let f be a Wiener process on [0,1]"   I'm a little confused...The "f" in the proposed algorithm, Is a continuos function or a Wiener process? In other words, to implement the algorithm, "f" is the contiuous given function defined on [0,1] or it is a Weiner process?

Assuming, for instance, $f(t):=(t-0.5)^4+t$ for each $t\in[0,1]$, We have to use this $f$ in the algorithm or we need to define "another" $f$ from this?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Did you realise that a Wiener process is a continuous function?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Thus, the Wiener process is the given function "f"?